# Errno::ENOSPC keeps happening even after space increases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I am using a Linux Ubuntu Server with nginx and passenger for a ruby on rails app.

I run out of space on my disk and got "An Errno::ENOSPC occurred". I tried to fix it by increasing the disk size but the error persists.

If I run df -l in the server I get:

[image]

If I run df -i I get:

[image]

Any idea what could be happening and how to solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solution: unmount the tmp directory (umount /tmp)